# Is it possible merging a people database from a different picasa installation into another

Tags: picasa

I have two different picasa installations with different people name tags. Some people are as well in the one Db as in the other, but on different pictures. I would like to integrate the tag information from one installation into the other, without using the web synchronisation, which would make this possible as far as I understand. Do there any tools exist to manage the picasa database, as it's SQLite based as I've seen. So it should be possible to extract the face templates.

Answer (score 1):

Try to backup both contacts.xmls from `users\appdata\local\google\picasa2\contacts` and merge the entries into one file by appending the extra entries between the first and last lines.

You can rename people as necessary in this file if you want to avoid duplicates. Then copy (or map a drive) to the set of photos that you want to merge in, add it (or remove/re-add it if there already) as a folder to be scanned in Picasa tools/folders and let Picasa do its work.

Eventually it starts adding the new people from your merged `contacts.xml`. It takes hours rather than minutes, but it does get there.